# Var status doesn't evaluates into an array on js

Tags: javascript

If i write the following in the js console

```
var status = ["POR ENTREGAR","POR ENTREGAR","POR ENTREGAR"];
status;
```

It evaluates to a string "POR ENTREGAR,POR ENTREGAR,POR ENTREGAR" why is this the result and not the equivalent array? I'm going nuts

If you then write status[0] it returns P; Please before answering try with another array so you can see how the console prints strings and arrays differently.

Comment: which console?  what browser? you may be seeing the `toString ()` representation of the array. What does `typeof status` return?

Comment: Because the JS console can only output strings? Try `console.dir(status);`

Comment: are you seeing that string after doing `alert(status);` if so, thats just how it looks, it is in fact an array

Comment: no it actually evaluates to that in the console run t yourself and you'll see. then try status[0] it returns P

Comment: @zardilior Tyler's answer about the `status` property on `window` may be on to something. Try calling your variable anything other than `status`. EDIT: Seems Kooilnc found it out himself!

Comment: thnx lol it did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript comes with a built in status property on the window object, which is an empty string. Change the variable name to something other than status and you'll be good to go.

Not sure why the downvote. Check it.

Some code which demonstrates the same problem.

```
    var status = {}
    status ---> "[object Object]"
    typeof status ---> "string"
```

Comment: I think this answer is actually hinting at the cause, possibly without realizing it. EDIT: Kooilnc seems to have gotten it.

Answer (score 1):

`status` Is a (sort of) [**reserved word**](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)<sup>**1**</sup>, so assign the array to another variable name, or assign it within a non global context:

```js
// [status] assigned within the global (window) context
var status   = ["POR ENTREGAR","POR ENTREGAR","POR ENTREGAR"];
var mystatus = ["POR ENTREGAR","POR ENTREGAR","POR ENTREGAR"];
Helpers.log2Screen('`status` is array? ',  (status instanceof Array).yn());
Helpers.log2Screen('`mystatus` is array? ', (mystatus instanceof Array).yn());

statusStatus();

function statusStatus() {
  // [status] assigned within the statusStatus context
  var status   = ["POR ENTREGAR","POR ENTREGAR","POR ENTREGAR"];
  Helpers.log2Screen('`status` (in `statusStatus` context) is array? ',  
                     (status instanceof Array).yn());
}
```

```html
<script src="http://kooiinc.github.io/JSHelpers/Helpers-min.js"></script>
```

<sup>**1**</sup> If status is not assigned in the global (i.e. `window`) context, you're fine, see `statusStatus` within the snippet. Otherwise, you are overwriting the predefined existing `window.status`. Actually, `window.status` changes the text on the status bar of the browser, that's why it is always autoboxed to a string value (note: newer browsers seem to have ditched the status bar (chrome, firefox) or made it readonly (IE), but the thereby useless window property still exists).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more array format than string format, consider using console.dir(status) or console.table(status)